# Java escaping chars that already exist in the string

Tags: java, escaping, decimal

I need to escape chars that exist within a string but the escape chars are part of the escape code ie.

```
    Map<String, String> escapeChars = new HashMap<String, String>();
        escapeChars.put("^", "^94;");
        escapeChars.put("%", "^37;");
        escapeChars.put("'", "^39;");

    public String findEscapeChars(String x) {
    for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : escapeChars.entrySet()) {
        if(x.contains(entry.getKey()) ) {   
            x = x.replaceAll(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
    }
    return x;
    }

    //result should match
    assertEquals("^37;", findEscapeChars("%")); //example of the caret symbol escaping
    assertEquals("^37; 1 2 ^39; ^94; 4 ^37;", findEscapeChars("% 1 2 ' ^ 4 %"));
```

It really needs to done in one loop and only one if condition. The problem is that the hash map doesn't traverse in a certain order therfore the caret symbol could try escape itself in the string. It seems to be tricky without numerous loops and if conditions, a simple solution would be ideal.

Thanks
D

Comment: Are the source characters always a single character? I'll write an answer assuming that's the case...

Comment: "It really needs to done in one loop and only one if condition." Why?

Comment: If you are certain the order is the only thing getting in your way, go look up `LinkedHashMap`.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. The source varies from 0 to 160 chars. Only 1 loop and 1 condition for efficiency - it potentially could get called a couple of times every second. I think it would be bad practise for it to only work in a certain order, shouldn't be a solution that.

Comment: @dale: You can do an *awful* lot of work a couple of times per second. Go for the cleanest code to start with, and check whether it's fast *enough*, rather than going for the absolute fastest code and sacrificing readability.

Comment: I agree it has to be readable but with the product already doing many processes it's best that efficiency is priority.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to assume you only need to escape a single *character* at a time. Then you can do:

```
public String findEscapeChars(String original) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < original.length(); i++)
    {
        char c = original.charAt(i);
        String escaped = escapeMap.get(c);
        if (escaped != null)
        {
            builder.append(escaped);
        }
        else
        {
            builder.append(c);
        }
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Note that unless you really *need* to have the dynamic nature of a map, a simple switch would probably be simpler and more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for that, the char requires casting to string:              String escaped = escapeMap.get(Character.toString(c)); Also the map gets injected by spring, find the map makes it more extensible and wouldn't require the switch statement code to be change if a new escape char was required.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you need order in map use `LinkedHashMap` instead. Second, you even can solve everything without maps at all but using regular experession with lookahead. See http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html